# Plugin still uses the old version of Jquery even after hook_js_alter

Tags: hooks, javascript

I have drupal-7.34 installed and Im using Jquery Update 7.x-2.5 to make my plugins work.  Everything is working fine until I had use a plugin which needs a more recent version of Jquery(jquery 1.11.2).

I had found out that Jquery Update Module is only limited to Jquery 1.10, which doesnt suffice my plugins need. So what I did is use hook_js_alter and uninstalled Jquery Update 
Module.

```
function myid_js_alter(&$javascript) {
     // Swap out jQuery to use an updated version of the library. 
    $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'myid') . '/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js';
    dsm($javascript);
}
```

After doing so, I got a really mess up interface:

[image]

This is because the newer version is added last after the webcam plugins. I found it out by displaying `$javascript` in hook alter.

[image]
[image]

Below is my hook_init:

```
function myid_init() {
    //Webcam Plugin  
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "/photobooth-js-gh-pages/photobooth_min.js"); 
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "/photobooth-js-gh-pages/website/js/script.js");
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "/photobooth-js-gh-pages/website/css/page.css");
}
```

How to add the newer version of jquery before the plugins get added? or other way to achieve my goal without breaking drupal's default functionality?

Comment: Recommend opening up an issue in regards to 1.11.x here: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/jquery_update

Answer (score 0):

To change the jQuery library used by Drupal 7, you need to implement [`hook_library_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library/7), not `hook_js_alter()`.

```
function myid_library_alter(&$libraries, $module) {
  if ($module == 'system' && isset($libraries['jquery'])) {
    // Verify existing version is older than the one we are updating to.
    if (version_compare($libraries['jquery']['version'], '1.11.2', '<')) {
      $libraries['jquery']['version'] = '1.11.2';
      $libraries['jquery']['js']['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'myid') . '/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js';
    }
  }
}
```

Similar code is used by the jQuery Update module in [`jquery_update_library_alter()`](https://www.drupal.org/node/2462717).

As side note, you could be interesting in reading [Added methods to avoid loading jQuery and related JavaScript libraries on all pages when they are not needed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2462717). In short, Drupal 7.36 allows modules to tell Drupal if there is the need to load jQuery; this means [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) now executes the following code.

```
    // Add jquery.js, drupal.js, and related files and settings if they have
    // not been added yet. However, if the 'javascript_always_use_jquery'
    // variable is set to FALSE (indicating that the site does not want jQuery
    // automatically added on all pages) then only add it if a file or setting
    // that requires jQuery is being added also.
    if (!$jquery_added && (variable_get('javascript_always_use_jquery', TRUE) || $options ['requires_jquery'])) {
      $jquery_added = TRUE;
      // url() generates the prefix using hook_url_outbound_alter(). Instead of
      // running the hook_url_outbound_alter() again here, extract the prefix
      // from url().
      url('', array('prefix' => &$prefix));
      $default_javascript = array(
        'settings' => array(
          'data' => array(
            array('basePath' => base_path()),
            array('pathPrefix' => empty($prefix) ? '' : $prefix),
          ),
          'type' => 'setting',
          'scope' => 'header',
          'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
          'every_page' => TRUE,
          'weight' => 0,
        ),
        'misc/drupal.js' => array(
          'data' => 'misc/drupal.js',
          'type' => 'file',
          'scope' => 'header',
          'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
          'every_page' => TRUE,
          'weight' => -1,
          'requires_jquery' => TRUE,
          'preprocess' => TRUE,
          'cache' => TRUE,
          'defer' => FALSE,
        ),
      );
      $javascript = drupal_array_merge_deep($javascript, $default_javascript);
      // Register all required libraries.
      drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery', TRUE);
      drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.once', TRUE);
    }
```